# How can I enlarge a small photo with very high resolution to a big photo with less resolution?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution

How can I enlarge a small photo with very high resolution to a big photo with less resolution?

Original size is 12.7 width by 7.2 height at 1550 dpi.

I want to convert it to 62cm width by 182 cm height and at 300 to 400 dpi, and cut a part of the photo.

Answer (score 3):

Crop the image to just the part you need first, then, in the `Edit > Image Size` dialog, uncheck the `Resample` option and change the size to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit > Imagesize*, uncheck *Resample* and put in 182cm for height and 300-400 dpi as resolution. Make sure you have the "chain-symbol" active so your ratio does not change.

Then take the *Crop-Tool* (standard Shortcut: C) and change the mode in the Top-bar to Fixed-Size and type in 62cm as width and 182 cm as height. You can leave the Resolution blank. Then crop the cart from the image you want, and you're done.

hope this helped.